# WSGI, Werkzeug and form based authentication

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, security, wsgi, werkzeug

I would like to implement a WSGI/Werzeug based web application and need help implementing the form based authentication. I found repoze.who and think it solves most of my problems. It works fine with SqlAlchemy which I will use for my database code. What I'm looking for is code to have salted passwords, protection from session hijacking, ...

Are there any lighweight wsgi libraries to do that? I don't want to use a complete framework like Django, because I need more control over the details of request handling. But I would not like to implement security details on my own.

Answer (score 0):

[Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) is a good microframework to get you started. You can use [WTForms](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/) to handle the forms, SQLAlchemy as the ORM and [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/) to handle the templates. It's a good match.

EDIT: Flask has [some extensions](http://flask.pocoo.org/extensions/) that might help with what you need (Login extension?)

Comment: Nice tips, but not really an answer to my question regarding salted passwords and security stuff.